# Alternative to ldap_rename for Sun Directory Servers

Tags: php, ldap, sunone

PHP provides a great function for copying or moving directory records within LDAP. Unfortunately this `ldap_rename` function [doesn't seem to work on the Sun Directory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-rename.php#46625). Do any alternatives exist to change an account's OU without having to create a new account?

My end goal is to have a simple method to switch between two OU's, such as:
`CN=username,OU=Admin,DC=uaa,DC=alaska,DC=edu` to
`CN=username,OU=Student,DC=uaa,DC=alaska,DC=edu`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with LDIF. On the directory point of view, the job you want to do is called a DN modification, there are two LDAP verbs for that *moddn* and *modrdn*.

It can be done in LDIF by this way in OpenLDAP:

```
dn: CN=username,OU=Admin,DC=uaa,DC=alaska,DC=edu
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: CN=username
deleteoldrdn: 0
newsuperior: OU=Student,DC=uaa,DC=alaska,DC=edu
```

I use this way accros Active Directory :

```
dn: CN=username,OU=Admin,DC=uaa,DC=alaska,DC=edu
Changetype: moddn
Newrdn: CN=username
Deleteoldrdn: 1
Newsuperior: OU=Student,DC=uaa,DC=alaska,DC=edu
```

**Be careful**, *copy/delete* is significantly different from *moddn* and *modrdn* in the first solution you create new objects (new *guid* or *uuid* in the LDAP database) and it can impact replication. In the second solution you move objects.

Perhaps you can find there verbs in PHP.

Comment: If the directory server does not support the modrdn with newsuperior directive how it will work ldif file?

Comment: try moddn. What is your directory server ?